# Monitor /private/var/log/system.log for connected users

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, automation

How do I monitor system log for lines like:

`<host> sshd: <user> [priv][<process>]: USER_PROCESS: <process> ttys000`

I'd like to automate an AppleScript / bash script to interrupt me and display an approval / denial window:

`$(osascript -e '(display dialog "User $user connected. Kick out?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} default button 2 with title "SSH to $host")`

Ideally the kick would then automate the

`kill -9 <process>`

Comment: Interesting use case. You'd also need to add kill to the sudoers file if you don't log in as root (or otherwise handle the authentication needed for one user to kill a process belonging to another user. I'm not sure why you don't just lock down sshd - but the value in learning to script might be more important here than just preventing log in when you are using the machine and making it easy to "kick" them.

Comment: I have a guard user for purpose of kicking. Thanks for bringing this up. SSHD is opened for me to be able to monitor that system.

Comment: Here is an alternative approach https://m.habr.com/ru/post/441774/